# What does "feed store" mean?

Tags: meaning, definition

From the movie *Misery* (1990):

> What do you think I say when I go to **the feed store** in town? "Now,
>   Wally, give me a bag of that F-ing pig feed and 10 pounds of that
>   bitchly cow corn"?

From the context I can guess that a feed store is a store where you buy a food for your livestock. Is my guess correct? Or could a feed store mean a grocer?

Comment: The context indicates that it's a store where ypu buy food for your livestock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what a feed store is.

Note this is specifically food for livestock (horses, cows, pigs, chickens, etc.) and not (necessarily) pets.  Food for dogs, cats, birds, fish, gerbils, etc. is sold at a *pet* store.

Comment: I would say that there is some overlap between feed store and pet store here. I have been to feed mills that have sold both. This may be because of the overlap between what is livestock and what is a pet.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, *feed* here means "[food for domestic animals](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/feed)". You'd go to a feed store to buy food for livestock:

[image: CWW Feed Store and more]
<sub>[Image source](http://www.outdoorsnewmexico.com/2011/uncategorized/wildlife-and-more-at-cww-feed-store/)</sub>

Many feed stores may sell more than just feed. It's quite likely that they will sell other things needed for livestock, such as saddles, grooming products, and vaccines.